# How to get the current value of a piped/transformed BehaviourSubject

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable

How can I get the currentValue of the observable returned by `readValue()` below? (Without subscribing to it, I need the current value only, and do not wish to do anything with subsequent ones)

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});

observe(): Observable<Object> {
  return subject.pipe(map(mappingfunction));
}
```

Is it only possible to create another BehaviourSubject like so?

```
var other_subject = new BehaviorSubject<Object>();
observer().subscribe(other_subject);

var value = other_subject.currentValue();
```

Technically it should be possible to get the currentValue without that, since it will alawys be available, since the original behavioursubject will always play the last result through the pipe, right? Unless of course we do some bounce magic, but I don't intend to do anything like that.

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify that it should work correctly even with pipe, so long as you don't do anything in the pipe to delay things - take a look and let me know if I've missed anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe with a take(1) or first() operator to just get the current value synchronously, for example:

```
getCurrentValue(): Blah {
    let x: Blah = null;
    this.observe().pipe(take(1)).subscribe((a) => x = a);
    return x;
}
```

This works because a BehaviorSubject will always return the current value synchronously on initial subscription, this should always result in `x` having the current value of the subject. When constructing a BehaviorSubject, you always provide an initial value, so it will always have a value to give in this scenario.

Note that this only works for BehaviorSubjects (and observables derived/piped from them), it is not a general solution to the current value of an Observable as other subjects may not return the current value synchronously in this way.

So long as none of your pipe functions delay the emissions from the BehaviorSubject (e.g. you do not have debounceTime, delay, or anything like that in the pipe) this should work irrespective of the pipe.

Comment: Hmm is there a way to "take out" the value? without declaring the variable first then mutating its value?

Comment: @ÁkosVandra No, not that I know of. What would you need to do that for? I would suggest wrapping the above in a function (`getCurrentValue()` or similar) then you can just call that wherever you need the value.

Comment: @ÁkosVandra updated the answer to wrap it in a function to show what I mean. Obviously, change "Blah" to whatever the right type you're retrieving is :)

Comment: @ÁkosVandra I've posted another answer for a different option - I'm not sure which one is better for your use case so we can let the votes decide :)

Comment: Just to make it more functional / less imperative

Comment: @ÁkosVandra It feels like "I want to get the current value" is, itself, against the principles of a functional / reactive programming style. What is your actual use case for getting the current value?

Answer (score 1):

Another option to keep track of the current value, which may be more appropriate depending on your use case, would be to use the tap operator:

```
var subject = new BehaviorSubject<Object>({});
var currentValue: Object = null;

observe(): Observable<Object> {
    return subject.pipe(
        map(mappingfunction),
        tap((v) => currentValue = v)
    );
}
```

With this currentValue will contain the last emitted value from the observable at all times (although note it will not have any value until /something/ subscribes to the result of `observe()`).

Answer (score -2):

BehaviorSubject has a method getValue() to get the current value.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md#rxbehaviorsubjectprototypegetvalue

Comment: The result of a pipe is no longer a behaviorsubject, and as a result, the value is no longer accessible.